# Differents Tables in multiples objects blocs in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I don't know how can i get the result of different tables in one object, I want fill this objets with only a query...

```
class HomeDto
{
  String street;
  Room room1;
  Bath bath1;
}

//TABLE -> SIAS_TB_ROOM

class Room {
  String idHome;
  String floorRoom;
  String doorRoom;
}

//TABLE -> SIAS_TB_BATH

class Bath {
  String idHome;
  String floorBath;
  String doorBath;
}

<select id="findHome" 
    resultType="es.home.integration.model.HomeDto">

    SELECT room1.floorRoom, bath1.doorBath 
        FROM SIAS_TB_BATH bath, SIAS_TB_ROOM room 
    WHERE bath.idHome = room.idHome
    AND bath.floorBath='Purple'
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [result map](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps) for that like this:

```
<resultMap id="homeMap" type="es.home.integration.model.HomeDto">
   <id property="id" column="idHome"> <!-- you need to add id to home -->
   <association property="room1" javaType="es.home.integration.model.Room">
       <result property="floorRoom" column="floorRoom"/>
       <result property="doorRoom" column="doorRoom"/>
   </association>
   <association property="bath1" javaType="es.home.integration.model.Bath">
       <result property="floorBath" column="floorBath"/>
       <result property="doorBath" column="doorBath"/>
   </association>
</resultMap>
```

Then use it in query:

```
<select id="findHome" resultMap="homeMap">
    SELECT room.*, bath.foorBath, bath.doorBath
        FROM SIAS_TB_BATH bath, SIAS_TB_ROOM room 
    WHERE bath.idHome = room.idHome
    AND bath.floorBath='Purple'
</select>
```

You can simplify mapping further (for columns that are named the same as properties) by using autoMapping for associations like this:

```
<resultMap id="homeMap" type="es.home.integration.model.HomeDto">
   <id property="id" column="idHome"> <!-- you need to add id to home -->
   <association property="room1" javaType="es.home.integration.model.Room" autoMapping=true/>
   <association property="bath1" javaType="es.home.integration.model.Bath" autoMapping=true>
       <result property="aName" column="otherName"/>
   </association>
</resultMap>
```